# edit quantity without redirecting to another page

Tags: multi-vendor, edit, qty-increment

we have a marketplace site. each seller/vendor have their own account....

we are displaying list of sellers products , qty, sku, price...etc in their account....

http://prntscr.com/8vgul0

we are using this code to display those information : http://pastebin.com/CvQkXZ2r

we have a edit button next to "Qty", if we click on that edit button, its redirecting to another page and than seller edit the information and save it.

we are using following code to edit :

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>" data-type="<?php echo $products->getTypeId(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $helper->__('Edit')?>" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Edit')?>" class="mp_edit"/>
```

what we need is if we click on "edit" button, then it should display text field as like in the image and update and cancel button below.[image]

**edited question** :

i am using this code for  onclick event on  image and call javascript function:

```
<img onclick="updateField(this, '. $product_id .'); return false"; src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>"
```

javascript function which i defined in onclick of image.

```
<?php $url='Mage::getUrl('module_name/index/updateField/');' ?>
<script type="text/javascript">

function updateField(image, product_id)
{
    new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $url ?>', {
        method: 'post',
        parameters: { id: fieldId, field: $(button).previous('input').getValue() }
    });
}
</script>
```

i Make function in  controller that i define in java script ajax url.

```
public function updateFieldAction()
{
    $fieldId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $field = $this->getRequest()->getParam('field');
    if ($fieldId) {
        $model = Mage::getModel('modulename/model')->load($fieldId);
        $model->setField($field);
        $model->save();
    }
}
```

design file = http://pastebin.com/hhWrn1gk &

controller file = http://pastebin.com/MBtE2hcS

but i am not getting solution....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this will work for you or not. For input text box on edit click you will need to change code as per below.

```
    <!--    edit qty -->
<td>
    <?php echo (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($products)->getQty(); ?>
    <input type="text" id="qty_<?php echo $product_id;?>" name="qty" value="<?php echo (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($products)->getQty(); ?>" style="display:none"/>
    <span class="label wk_action">
        <img onclick="updateField('<?php echo $product_id; ?>');return false;" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>"/>
    </span>   
</td>


<?php $url = Mage::getUrl('module_name/index/updateField/'); ?>

<script type = "text/javascript" >

    var $wk_jq = jQuery.noConflict();

    function updateField(product_id)
    {
        var qtyId = '#qty_'+product_id;

        $wk_jq(qtyId).toggle()

        $qty = $wk_jq(qtyId).val();

        new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $url ?>', {
            method: 'post',
            parameters: {id: product_id, qty: $qty}
        });
    }
</script>
```

I didn't tried it but you might be need to change as per your requirement and will need to change in controller file as well.

Comment: controller file http://pastebin.com/HV6YKVXA

Comment: i added from line 12 to 21 in above code, but its not saving the quantity. if i click on update button, i am getting message " product is deleted"

Comment: i can able to edit only for the  1st product in the list. i can not able to edit other products

Comment: Can you check the id of input qty box? It should not same for all

Comment: can you please inform how i can check this ? this is the complete code : http://pastebin.com/Ga326CXi

Comment: do you have a live URL?

Comment: pease let me know if you need any other informatin

Comment: you don't getting product id <?php echo $product_id; ?> and this is the reason id is being same for all like id="qty_" and also blank value is passing in onclick="updateField(''); you need to check why you are not getting value for <?php echo $product_id; ?>

Comment: okay, i will check it...

Comment: ok and this is the reason when you click on the any of edit link only first input box is showing

Comment: @Akilesh Patel we are using this code to get quantity = > http://pastebin.com/JEn86y3X now  , please tell me what 

i have to replace with " <?php echo $product_id; ?>" to get it work all products